# jackson exclude subclass field

Tags: java, json, jackson

Given the follwing POJO:

```java
class A {
 private String name;
 private String desc;
 private List<A> subclasses;
}
```

I would produce that kind of json, by excluding a the field desc` from the subclass :

```js
{
 name : "aname"
 desc: "adesc",
 subclasses : [{
      name : "aname"
 },{
      name : "anotherame"
 }]
}
```

Or a field from the parent class and not from the child class

Answer (score 2):

To exclude a field use a `@JsonIgnore` annotation. Look more over here -

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?92684-Exclude-bean-field-from-JSON-response

and here -

http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.0.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnore.html

Comment: With `@JsonIgnore` my field will always be excluded, I would like to exclude it depending on the context, in the example above, exclude the `name` field from the `subclasses` instances but not from the instance that contains them.

Comment: Then create a class that extends another class, where the upper class doesn't contain those fields. Try to make such a workaround.